# Problema em caracteres UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

to com um erro no meu site, em questão de `UTF-8`

Se eu uso `á` ele vai pro link como `%E3%83%E2%A1` e printa no input como `%e3%83%e2%a1` na hospedagem.

Mas no localhost ele vai como `ã¡` e volta como `%c3%a3%c2%a1`.

Os códigos que estou usando são esses:

Para mostrar o Código:

```
function mostrar($string) {
    $string = str_replace('+', ' ', $string);

    $string = utf8_decode($string);

    return mb_strtolower( strip_tags( trim( $string ) ) );
}
```

Para Enviar o Código:

```
function limpar($string) {
        $string = str_replace(' ', '+', $string);

        $string = utf8_encode($string);

        return mb_strtolower( strip_tags( trim( str_replace('/', '', $string) ) ) );
    }
```

Enviando pro `header('Location')`para aparecer na url do site:

```
if(isset($_POST['procm-p']) or isset($_POST['procm-s'])){

        $pesquisa = strip_tags($_POST['procm-s']);

        if(isset($pesquisa) and !empty($pesquisa)){

            $link = $surl.'p/'.limpar($pesquisa);

            header("Location: ".$link);

        }else{

            echo '<script>alert("Pesquisa Invalida");</script>';

        }

    }
```

Printando no input:

```
<input type="text" name="procm-s" value="<?php echo mostrar( $url[1] ); ?>" placeholder="Procurar Musicas" />
```

Como está o form:

```
<div id="pesquisa2">
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" method="post" name="procm">
        <input type="text" name="procm-s" value="<?php echo mostrar($url[1]); ?>" placeholder="Procurar Musicas" />
        <input type="submit" value="Procurar" name="procm-p" id="btn" />
    </form> 
</div>
```

Coloquei o site no ar para que possam ver: http://procurar.netescola.info/

O que eu queria é que ele fosse como um `utf-8 encoded` e voltasse como `utf-8` normal, mas isso não acontece.

E se notar como eu disse acima, ele tem uma diferença imensa entre o meu `localhost` e minha `hospedagem`.

Sabem oque pode ser? estou usando `utf8_encode()` e `utf8_decode()` e até mesmo `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O PHP já tem funções específicas para tratar URL, que são [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php) e [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php). Notar que elas já resolvem a troca do `+` por espaço, pois isto faz parte do padrão de *encoding* de URL usado pelo *mime type* `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Para fins de comparação, a [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rawurlencode.php) é parecida, mas não tem o mesmo comportamento com o sinal de `+`. Esta já segue a [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986).

É importante notar também que se sua página já está em UTF-8, você não deve usar [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) nem [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php), pois são funções para trocar a codificação de uma string ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8, e vice-versa.

Links para o manual do PHP:

- **[`string urlencode ( string $str )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php)**
- **[`string urldecode ( string $str )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php)**
- **[`string utf8_encode ( string $data )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php)**
- **[`string utf8_decode ( string $data )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php)**